# understanding services and controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm brand new to AngularJS (specifically using ionic).

I'm trying to build an app that downloads 'posts' and then downloads 'users' based on the posts user_id.

I have a "Posts" service that makes an API call to download all of the posts per a Posts.get(); function. It works and the posts come back. My controller sets an arraylist $scope.posts  = Posts.all() which simply returns the posts.

Now using ng-repeat I can have it post to the screen each post id as they come in and that's working fine.

Where I'm getting confused is how do I now download each user associated with post.user_id and attach them together.

If I inject the Users model into Posts and vice versa so they can update and call functions on each other, it gives me a "Circular Dependency" error.

If I try to inject $scope into the models, so as to call a function on the controller to connect them, it throws an "Unknown Provider $scopeProvider" error.

What is the proper way of handling a situation like this in AngularJS?

Download a post, from that information download a user, then display the information onto the screen of the post and user for that post.

Any help or tips would be awesome! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a title more specific to your problem. Maybe "How to Associate User ID and User Data from different services."

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only need a one-way dependency, you should be able to inject Users into Posts without any trouble.

The other thing you can do if you also need to fetch posts based off of a user, is to have a third service that depends on Posts and Users and will make calls to both of these.

For example you could have

```
// posts.js
angular.module('myapp.posts', []).factory('Posts', ...)
// users.js
angular.module('myapp.users', []).factory('Users', ...)
// users-for-posts.js
angular.module('myapp.users-for-posts', ['myapp.posts', 'myapp.users'])
       .factory('UsersForPosts', function(Posts, Users) {
          // ...
       })
```

(you don't have to have separate modules, but I'd recomend it)

Comment: Correct, I can inject Users into Posts. I've tried this. So now the posts get downloaded, then it calls a function in users to download the user. So now I have an array of all the posts and an array of all the users great. Now how do I display this? I tried something like this in my ng-repeat of post in posts : {{ Users.find(post.user_id).user_id }}  and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: http requests in angular always return a promise, which is why your existing code wasn't working. You should have something along the lines of

`getPosts.then(function (posts) {posts.forEach(function(p){ User.find(p.user_id).then(function(u){p.user = u})}) }})`

in your service